# In tensorflow, when I use DNNLinearClassifier [wide_n_deep_tutorial.py], how to restore the history model trained out and train base on it

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was learning the Google [wide and deep model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide_and_deep) in tensorflow.

My code was modified based on the [tf example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py).

My question is:

1. How to load history model, and train new sample based on it. I had search many on the web, but most methods are like the following code.

   Examples of saver

   ```
   v1 = tf.Variable(..., name="v1")
   v2 = tf.Variable(..., name="v2")
   ...
   init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
   saver = tf.train.Saver()
   with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(init_op)
      ..
      save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
   ```

   But in `wide_n_deep` train, it define a method "build_estimator" which returns:

   `m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier`.

   When I use the method above to define a saver, it gave error no Varibles to save. And the "m" returned have no save, restore method.

   I have also try `model.load` in `tflearn`, but it also doesn't work.
2. Second is related with above, how to save model. Or how to use model which the fit method saved in /tmp/. (checkpoint)

My question can be summarized as:

How to save model and restore history model when I use the  `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier` in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

There is an argument called `model_dir` in `DNNLinearCombinedClassifier`: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py#L476. Just point it to the directory where you store your model checkpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Is not the para model_dir the dir to save model this train generate? Or the dir for load model and the dir for save model can be the same? If the answer is yes, and the load is automatically load the last model?  Thanks once again.

Comment: The dir can be used for both loading model checkpoint before training and for saving model checkpoints after certain steps.

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: I have  a new question, if I want to check the model parameters,  what should I do to print the model parameter. I tried `graph_def = tf.GraphDef();
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read()) 
` But it gives an error: google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Tag had invalid wire type.